# Add style color to an appended li - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When adding a new item to the list i would like it to change color based on the input value.

How do i add the input.value to my new appended li item?

I have created a codepen if anyone would be able to help 
http://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/mOBjvQ

```
// DIV TOGGLE
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggleList');
const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list');

// User INPUT
const userInput = document.querySelector('.userInput');
const button = document.querySelector('button.description');
const p = document.querySelector('p.description');
let listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// ADD ITEM
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('button.addItemButton');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    listItem[i].style.color = userInput.value;
  }

  p.innerHTML = userInput.value + ':';
});

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (listDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    listDiv.style.display = 'block';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Hide list';
  } else {
    listDiv.style.display = 'none';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Show list';
  }
});

addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('ul');
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  let appendedItem = list.appendChild(li);

  console.log(appendedItem);

  for (let i = 0; i < appendedItem.length; i++) {
    appendedItem[i].style.color = userInput.value;
  }

  console.log(appended item);

  addItemInput.value = '';
});
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Native javascript is better! */rants*

Comment: @Roberrrt jQuery *is* written in native JS. `;)`

Comment: Haha, I know, I know. Let's create both answers, I'll write the native one, you're up for the jQuery one?

Comment: The codepen code is not working

Comment: if you wanna try jquery then use this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNePje

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new one :

```
//DIV TOGGLE
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggleList');
const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list');
var lastPickedColor = "black"; // it will store the last picked color
//User INPUT
const userInput = document.querySelector('.userInput');
const button = document.querySelector('button.description');
const p = document.querySelector('p.description');
let listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li');

//ADD ITEM
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('button.addItemButton');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   lastPickedColor = userInput.value;
   for(let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
     listItem[i].style.color = lastPickedColor;
   }
   p.innerHTML = userInput.value + ':';
});

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (listDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    listDiv.style.display = 'block';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Hide list';
  } else {
    listDiv.style.display = 'none';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Show list';
  }
});

addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('ul');
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.style.color = lastPickedColor; // so it will add li with last picked color
  li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  let appendedItem = list.appendChild(li);
  console.log(appendedItem);
  for(let i = 0; i < appendedItem.length; i++) {
    appendedItem[i].style.color = userInput.value;
  } 
  console.log(appendeditem);
  addItemInput.value = '';
});
```

I added lastPickedColor variable to top of the page whenever you change the color, it will store the lastPickedColor and all list add with this color.

Comment: I didn't down vote this Erol , it does work how i want. Thank you ! :-) , i don't know why it is

Comment: Okay sir, sorry for misunderstanding :) I thank you too.

Comment: I'm not sure why either, but downvoting other answers because yours got downvoted is just silly.

Comment: Actually i didn't do it for rage, i think the better way is this code but i undoed it mate i don't want to cause any hearthbreak :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple.

You're defining the initial list when the js is executed, but the new element is created dynamically. Therefore, you'll have to create a new nodelist based on all elements, including the new one. You can simply redefine it inside the current click event:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li');
   for(let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        listItem[i].style.color = userInput.value;
   }
   p.innerHTML = userInput.value + ':';
});
```

To give it the same color as the existing ones, change this function to apply the styling directly on the latest added element:

```
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('ul');
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  let appendedItem = list.appendChild(li);
  appendedItem.style.color = userInput.value;
  addItemInput.value = '';
});
```

[Working codepen example](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/gLGdMN)

Comment: Hi Robert , i am trying to add the input value to the new appended list item. So when i add a new list item it will be the colour of the input.value above

Comment: You mean, appending the *color* you're trying to change?

Comment: how it works in erols answer , Thank you anyway i'm not the best at asking questions (need more practice)

Comment: Yeah, although you should combine the solutions. In case you'd change the color *after* you've added a new list item.

Answer (score 0):

so I have made 2 changes for your code to work. Please see
http://codepen.io/amoolya/pen/GNMXqa?editors=1111

First change

```
   addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
       let list = document.querySelector('ul');
       let li = document.createElement('li');
       li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
       let appendedItem = list.appendChild(li); 
       appendedItem.style.color =  list.firstElementChild.style.color; //The newly appended item is given the color of the first list element. In your case, this would be whatever color the user chose last.
   });
```

Second Change:

I added

```
       document.querySelectorAll('li');
```

inside your event handler for the color change button so that each time, the length of the new list is calculated.